# Powershell size vs size on disk comparrision

Tags: powershell, directory, size

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that can be ran across a NAS to find any large discrepancies in a directories size and its size on disk.

I have been unable to find a command that can get the size on disk (as reported in a folders properties). Most tutorials use the `Measure-Object -property Length` which only seems to report the actual size.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: This is my opinion, not an answer. Your best bet is to find a tool that can calculate folder size, or can maintain an index of folder sizes so that it can be looked up quickly without doing too much duplicate work. In order to calculate "folder size" you need the folder size of all sub-folders as well. Any attempt to build this in PowerShell is going to be a pain and likely result in overlapping/duplicate scans. So I would suggest finding a CLI tool that can quickly calculate folder sizes, or even better, one that maintains a folder size index so that it doesn't need to be done on the fly.

Comment: One program I like to use personally, but I do not know how well it scales is called "Everything", made by voidtools. It indexes EVERY file on the system and allows for extremely fast searching. You can optionally enable indexing file/folder sizes. You could then use their CLI tool to look up folder size information, however, I've never done it. I just tested it out and it works well, but not sure how to look up folder sizes for individual folders. Works great if you want a list though.

Comment: The discrepancies you refer to is caused by the cluster size of the file system you use and the amount of files smaller than this size. If the most of your files on those disks are much smaller than the cluster size you waste some disk space and you may consider using a smaller cluster size. Is it really that much that you need to consider?

Comment: This might help: [Cluster size is too large](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/disk-space-problems-on-ntfs-volumes#cluster-size-is-too-large) ... and this maybe: [Default cluster size for NTFS, FAT, and exFAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95)